# imageview onClickHandler gives its id as -1

Tags: android

I've got many of such ImageViews

```
<ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/img23"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler">
```

image view successfully calls the method "myClickHandler(View v)"

in that method

```
public void myClickHandler(View v) {
    Log.i("V Class",""+v.getClass().toString()+" "+
          v.getHeight()+" X "+v.getWidth()+" "+v.getId());
}
```

Although the log prints

```
09-09 12:48:10.401: INFO/V Class(17399): class android.widget.ImageView 59 X 59 -1
```

here i got class name(ImageView), height X width, but
somehow i am not able to get Id of the image clicked....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you haven't given an id to your View.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/my_view_id"
    android:src="@drawable/img23"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler">
```

Comment: Basically exactly what I told OP. Do you think this could be the problem? I'm not very experienced with Android...

Comment: This is the problem. `getId` returns -1 if the View has no id.

Answer (score 1):

In your XML `android:id` is not defined: could this lead to this behaviour?

Comment: yeah it led me to problem when i tried to access that ID...
actually i had 100s of such images and i was lazy to give ids to each of the image... that time i had no plan to use it in this manner...
still thanks..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img234" 
    android:src="@drawable/img23"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler">
```

Comment: Basically exactly what I told OP. Do you think this could be the problem? I'm not very experienced with Android...